# Dropzone with django image upload

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Im trying to upload images using Dropzone.js .
There doesnt seem to be any current tutorials for Dropzone although i used this link: https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/dropzonejs-django-how-to-build-a-file-upload-form/

Essentially what i want to do is , The user uploads  multiple images  . a hotel_id is attached to the images and stored in the hotelphotos table as a url which is unique each time .

**MY code**

**Models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
     hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     path = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%M/%d)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PhotosForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
   model = Photo
   fields = ['path']
```

**views.py**

```
def uploadPhoto(request,hotelid):
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = PhotosForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
     new_file = Photo(path = request.FILES['file'] , hotel_id = hotelid)
     new_file.save()
   else:
     form = PhotosForm()
     hotelid = hotelid
   data = {'form': form, 'hotelid':hotelid}
   return render(request, template , data)
```

**The form**

```
<form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'ManageHotels:uploadPhoto' hotelid %} method = "POST">

</form>
```

Files uploaded dont get created and the url also doesnt add to the database.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: pk doesn't seem to be defined, you also have request.FILEs it should be request.FILES and your class and action don't close on your form

Comment: Hi , Sorry , they were just typos in the actual question not in the code.

Comment: Dropzone Accepts that a photo has been uploaded , I also see the post request in inspect. However after that nothing happens.

Comment: Oh fair play have you tried just using form.save() as your using a model form?

Comment: I should have added that im fairly new to django and python for that matter. Would form.save() go after the new_file.save()?

Comment: No worries we were all new once :) and just replace the two lines after form.is_valid() for form.save()

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I ran out of time and used another fileupload instead . Thanks for trying dude , il surely attempt your fix next time i use dropzone.js